# DELETE command of SQL

Tags: php, mysql

While using PHP and MySQL, I applied DELETE command like this:

```
$query="DELETE FROM email_list WHERE email ="."$email";
mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
```

It didn't work.
But when I put it like this:

```
$query="DELETE FROM email_list WHERE email ='$email'";
mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
```

This works. I want to know why concatenation doesn't work. Here $dbc is my database and $email stores email I want to delete while email_list is my table in $dbc database table.

Comment: Concatenation does work; but you still need the single quotes around `$email` in your finished query. They're missing in the first one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well your first construction results in a query like this:

```
DELETE FROM email_list WHERE email =user@example.com
```

And your second results in:

```
DELETE FROM email_list WHERE email ='user@example.com'
```

So you tell me!

Answer (score 2):

Your concatenation doesn't work because it is missing the single quotes. Correct way would be to do it like this:

```
$query="DELETE FROM email_list WHERE email = '" . $email . "'";
mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
```

Which is really unsafe and breaks if `$email` contains single quotes.

**Protect against SQL injection**

Since you're already using `mysqli` you should modify your query to a prepared statement:

```
/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM email_list WHERE email = ?")) {
    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

This immediately protects your script against [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and saves you from the quote-escaping-hassle.

Comment: +1 for mentioning SQL injection. As is, this script looks really unsafe.

Answer (score 2):

You missed single quotes in your first query. So assuming `$email` contains value `example@example.com`, then  `$query` evalutated to :

```
 DELETE FROM email_list WHERE email =example@example.com
```

You would need to put it like this correctly:

```
$query="DELETE FROM email_list WHERE email ='"."$email'";
$query="DELETE FROM email_list WHERE email ="."'$email'";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "DELETE FROM email_list WHERE email = '".$email."'";
mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
```

You have to put strings in a query in quotes, but you don't need quotes to concat a variable

Answer (score 1):

The `$email` contains probably a string which has to be wrapped within quotes. You did some quotes but right around the variable name, which doesn't help much.

wrong:

```
$query="DELETE FROM email_list WHERE email ="."$email";
```

right:

```
$query="DELETE FROM email_list WHERE email ='".$email."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. It is because you need to make sure that you are concatenating your strings correctly!

```
$foo = "harry " . "styles";
echo $foo
```

Only outputs `harry styles`. With MySQL, the command that you need is `... WHERE email = 'email_address';`, so you need to ensure that the string is correctly created!

Check out the PHP manual page http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php which goes on about string concatenation.